# relationships in Laravel tables no id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I have two tables A and B
Table A contains the site field, table B contains the site_id field
I need to link these two tables by site field from table A.

```
            $table->bigInteger("site_id")->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('site_id')
                ->references('site')
                ->on('data_args')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
```

getting this error - MySQL Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: It is better to create `Sites` table and connect it to `A` table. Then you can connect A to `Sites`. Always try to use coding standards, follow principles and keep your Database structure well.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say tables have the following fields:

`table_a` = (id, description)

`table_b` = (id, site_id, site_field)

Then you want to connect `table_a` and `table_b`, so on `table_b`:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('site_id')->nullable(false);
$table->foreign('site_id')->references('id')->on('table_a');
```

Use `unsignedBigInteger()` instead of `bigInteger()->unsigned()`


`references` = the field to reference

`on` =  name of the table

Answer (score 0):

Two fields primary key and foreign key should be same data type
site_id is **bigInteger**, the another table primary key should be **bigInteger**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).